# How to empty the HTML of a table , before appending it in a for loop, using jquery,

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am appending the rows and columns to the table based on for loop but I need to empty the existing HTML, just to make my table resizeable. I tried ("table").empty(); but I am not able to place that code properly. Because it's adding rows and columns from for loop and if I apply above empty code its keep on empty the table HTML

Here is the below code which I write to append html

```
function draw(width, height){
    for(let i = 0; i < height; i++){
         $("#submit").click(function(){
        $("table").append("<tbody><tr></tr></tbody>");
    });

    }

    for(let j = 0; j < width; j++){
       $("#submit").click(function(){
        $("tr").append("<td></td>");    
      });
    }
}
```

Comment: You function makes no sense. You keep adding click handlers over and over to the same element. Specifically your function only adds event listeners, the function itself changes *nothing* in your table.

Comment: Please describe what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to create a table programmatically with `width` columns and `height` rows, this would achieve that:

```js
const table = document.getElementById('theTable');
const form = document.getElementById('createTableForm');

function drawTable(height, width) {
  
  table.innerHTML = '';
  let tbody = document.createElement('tbody');
  for (let i = 0; i < height; i++) {
    let row = document.createElement('tr');
    for (let j = 0; j < width; j++) {
      let cell = document.createElement('td');
      cell.textContent = `${i+1}/${j+1}`;
      row.appendChild(cell);
    }
    tbody.appendChild(row);
  }
  table.appendChild(tbody);
  document.body.appendChild(table);
}

form.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); // stop the form submit
  drawTable(tHeight.value, tWidth.value);
});
```

```css
table,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

td {
  font-size: 8px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<form id="createTableForm">
  <label>Number of rows: <input type="number" value="10" id="tHeight" /></label>
  <br />
  <label>Number of cols: <input type="number" value="10" id="tWidth" /></label>
  <br />
  <button type="submit">Draw table</button>
</form>

<table id="theTable"></table>
```

Comment: I tried it too. But I am adding the rows and columns in for loop. So its keep on emptying it and adding it. So I am not getting the actual reponse

Comment: So empty it before the loops start. You also need to understand that your function `draw()` does not change anything about the table; instead it just creates a bunch of event listeners.

Comment: I did that but its not empty the existing table   function draw(width, height){
   $("table").empty();
 for(let i = 0; i < height; i++){

   $("#submit").click(function(){
        
        $("table").append("<tbody><tr></tr></tbody>");
    });
  
 }

Comment: You function makes no sense. You keep adding click handlers over and over to the same element.

Comment: Okay, I have a form and submit button, so from form, it will take the value of height and width, and on click of submit it will generate the table. Please let me know how can i optimize this code if I did something wrong. Its my first time I used jquery

Comment: I wouldn't even use jQuery for that. I posted a pure Javascript solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could add `id` to the table to avoid affecting other tables, and set the HTML before heading to for loop:

```
$("#tableID").html("");
```

---

Update:

The accepted answer is great.

You can also check this code: https://codepen.io/shisaq/pen/qYKxKx

Comment: Its not effecting the other tables. suppose I added rows n columns, if I again run for loop, it will keep on adding and will not delete the existing one